# Bringing back distinct types with occurences in Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know that `$things->lists('type')` brings back distinct types in my collection, but how do I go about bringing back the distinct types with the number of times they appear in the collection?

Ideally ending up with something like this for 'types':

```
array(
    'type A' => 4,
    'type B' => 1
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not filtering distinct rows directly with a db query but afterwards on the collection, you unfortunately can't use a SQL `COUNT(*)` for that.

I don't know of any Laravel way to do it. But it's actually pretty easy with plain PHP

```
$list = $things->lists('type');

$types = array();
foreach($list as $type){
    if(!isset($types[$type])){
        $types[$type] = 0;
    }
    $types[$type]++;
}
```